# Additional columns in ContentType do not render in Page Layout in SharePoint 2010

Tags: content-type

I created a content type and used that to create a page layout. It works fine. Now I need to add few more columns to content type. These columns also show up in SharePoint designer Toolbox and I drag and drop them on Page Layout, but they do not render in the browser.

I have tested multiple times with different content types and page layouts. Looks like once you use a content type with a page layout, any new columns I add after that, would not render. Do I have to do anything special here for Page Layout to be able to render columns that were added later? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code that appeared? Also this may seem silly.. but are you sure you filled the new columns with values to display?

Comment: Another thing to check is that you have checked in your page layouts ... or users will still be seeing the old versions.  again something silly to check.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the fact that the columns that you added to the contenttype has not been propagated properly to the Pages-library. This is a real hassle in SharePoint. I like to create a feature receiver and programmatically ensure that any changes to existing contenttypes are being done.
If you create a new web and use the same pagelayout, does it work then?